# Subtract larger array by smaller array segment-wise

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Array_B has 47 elements and Array_A has 10 . I want to subtract the bigger array element-wise and in segments.

That is, Array_B is split into 4 segments of 10 and is subtracted element-wise from Array_A. How do I handle the remaining 7 elements of Array_B?

EDIT: Rephrased for clarity

Comment: Can you give an example and explain, how "0.7 elements" should be interpreted?

Comment: @user8408080 I rephrased the question.

Comment: And the answer from hpaulj is not what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is a bit vague, but my guess is that `np.resize` would do the trick:

```
In [104]: A = np.arange(1,5)
In [105]: B = np.arange(10,5*4.7)
In [106]: B
Out[106]: 
array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22.,
       23.])
In [107]: np.resize(A,B.shape)
Out[107]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2])
In [108]: B-np.resize(A,B.shape)
Out[108]: 
array([ 9.,  9.,  9.,  9., 13., 13., 13., 13., 17., 17., 17., 17., 21.,
       21.])
```

This takes advantage of how `np.resize` fills the empty spaces.  I don't normally use `resize`, but in this case it might just be right thing.